# find out SQL DB present or not using Nodejs

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

How to find out SQL DB is present or not if not present then create a new Database and if database is present then print database is connected successfully using nodejs

I know how to connect database and create a new database but want to check if database already present or not

any solution please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is information available in the information schema.

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA  WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'test';
```

If you don't have access to the information schema, you can run a command to create a database if it doesn't exist:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_tablename
```